# Installing Predator RGB Keyboard on Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-backlight

Hi I would like to install this:https://github.com/JafarAkhondali/acer-predator-turbo-and-rgb-keyboard-linux-module on my Predator laptop with ubuntu(22.04) on it. My question is, how do I use:

> chmod +x ./*.sh

Do I replace the star with some file/folder name?

This is the error that I get:

> line 203, in with open(CHARACTER_DEVICE, 'wb') as cd: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/acer-gkbbl-0'

Comment: I think that is clearly described on Github. If you follow those instructions step by step you should succeed. Your error has nothing to do with setting the executable flag. I think your error stems from using the python script - but you didn't elaborate.